# Sort list by length of str(item)

Tags: python

How would I sort the following list in python:

```
l = ['1', 'hello',  2, '11', 'aaaaaaaaa']
"sorted"(l) = ['1', 2, '11', 'hello', 'aaaaaaaaa']
```

Essentially, I want to sort by the length of the item, if it were converted to a string if it is is not already.

Comment: Exactly what is the length of `2`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
In [10]: l = ['1', 'hello',  2, '11', ]

In [11]: sorted(l, key=lambda x:len(str(x)))
Out[11]: ['1', 2, '11', 'hello']
```

Comment: or `l.sort(key=lambda x:len(str(x)))` for an in place sort

Comment: And if you want items of equal length to be sorted on value you could use `key=lambda x:(len(str(x)), str(x))` although in that case it's probably more efficient to convert everything to str first, eg `l = [str(x) for x in l]; l.sort(key=lambda x:(len(x), x))`